# How to sign Qt app with Mac Developer Id?

Tags: macos, code-signing, osx-mountain-lion, qt4.7, osx-gatekeeper

I have my first cross-platform app ready to release, developed with Qt 4.7.4, using Qt Creator (not Xcode).  I thought I had everything ready to go:  I have a script that runs `macdeployqt` and produces a .dmg, which works great.  I'm not planning to put this app in the Mac App Store.  Users will just download the .dmg from our web site.

However, on Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, Gatekeeper's default will cause confusion for my users if I don't have a developer id associated with my app.

I've googled quite a bit, and am pretty confused about what I need to do.  I've never done anything with code signing before, and very little with Mac's keychains.  What are the steps to take a completed Qt app and get it associated a developer id, so Gatekeeper at its default setting will be happy with my dmg and not confuse my users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need three steps:
1. sign the bundle itself
2. sign the .dylib binaries inside the bundle
3. sign the Qt frameworks (mainly everything like Qt* inside the bundle)

The command used in all three steps is:

```
codesign --force --verify --verbose --sign 'YOUR IDENTITY HERE' HelloWorld.app
```

and similary for other files (.dylibs and Qt frameworks)
See [man codesign](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/codesign) for detailed explanations.
You should have generated a certificate and include it in your Keychan. If you don't know where to get a certificate from, well.. that's another topic.

Edit: added a more detailed article [HERE](http://successfulsoftware.net/2012/08/30/how-to-sign-your-mac-os-x-app-for-gatekeeper/).

Comment: Shouldn't be the lib and framework to sign first as signing them would change the signature of the bundle ?